# Why are my TeXShop 4.57 window and menu invisible after updating to macOS 11.1?

Tags: texshop, macos

TeXShop 4.57 repeatedly crashes and window and menus are invisible, only their outline is visible.

The problem report lists:

> Crashing on exception: The window has been marked as needing another Update Constraints in Window pass, but it has already had moreUpdate Constraints in Window passes that there are views in the window.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It sounds like you may need to download TeXshop and install it from scratch. (FWIW, I rund MacOS 11.1 and TeXshop 4.57, and I haven't experienced the issue you've encountered.)

Answer (score 1):

In an email communication with Richard Koch, I followed his advice and that solved the problem.

Here are the steps:

“1. Go to ~/Library/Preferences and find "TeXShop.plist".

2. Move this file to the desktop.
3. Now restart TeXShop.

When Big Sur was first given to developers, TeXShop had a problem with tools in the toolbar. This was fixed before the release of Big Sur, but because the tools changed, there were problems with saving their state in TeXShop Preferences.

The TeXShop.plist file holds TeXShop Preferences, so when TeXShop restarts it will recreate a new copy with default values.

After that you may need to reset any preferences you have set before.

If this fails to fix the problem, you can quit TeXShop and replace the new copy with the old one on the desktop and return to your original preferences.

Note that ~/Library is the Library folder in your home directory, often hidden by the finder.

Richard Koch“

[image: Problem solved!]

Comment: Please add information on where you are citing this from.  Better still say which of these steps you actually followed to solve your problem.

Comment: Edited answer to include steps to solve the problem, which were suggested by Richard Koch in en email message